# Censored Data Log Likelihood

Tags: survival, likelihood, expectation-maximization, censoring

Suppose we have a n random samples ($X_1,..., X_n$) from a negative exponential distribution. If lets say we have these n random samples are censored at t, such that ($X_1, ..., X_m$) are observed and ($X_{m+1}, ..., X_n$) exceeds t. The likelihood is the normal censored likelihood.

Question: is it possible to express the complete data's log likelihood as a function of the not complete data?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "complete data" and "not complete data."

Comment: @Xi'an $f$($x$;$\theta$)=$\theta e^{-\theta x}$ for $x$ > 0
Likelihood function:
 $L$($\theta$;$x_1, ..., x_n$)=$\prod_{i=1}^m$$f$($x_i$;$\theta$)$\prod_{i=m+1}^n$ $(1-$$F$($\tau$,$\theta$))

Comment: @whuber complete data: data not censored at $\tau$ thus likelihood is given by the first term in the likelihood function; not complete data: data censored at $\tau$ thus likelihood is given by the second term in the likelihood function

Comment: Doesn't the expression for $L$ in your comment answer the question?

Comment: Why do you call this a negative exponential? This is a regular exponential distribution, censored at $\tau$. And you wrote the observed likelihood. The complete likelihood will also involve the censored data, that is the $n-m$ unobserved $x_i$ larger than $\tau$.

Comment: @Xi'an I believe the second product in the expression for $L$ in an earlier comment accommodates the $n-m$ censored values.

Answer (score 1):

Literally, the answer to your question "is it possible to express the complete data's log likelihood as a function of the not complete data? " is NO.  For censored data, there will be many (infinitely) many ways to "complete" them.  Maybe you could ask what is the expected complete data likelihood, when conditioning with the censored data. That way of thinking leads to the EM-algorithm.